# iTunes Music download all songs to be available offline

Tags: itunes, music

I am traveling abroad next week and in order to preserve data, I want to download all music that I 'own' on iTunes Music to my device.

So I want to avoid downloading each song one by one.

One trick I can think of is to create a playlist of **all** songs and then hopefully I can download this new playlist so that all un-downloaded music will be downloaded.

Is there a better way to easily and quickly download all music at once?

Comment: How yo you sync your phone and your music? Are you using Apple Music and/or iCloud Music Library?

Comment: I am just using the Apple Music (monthly) service and I 'Add' music without downloading it so that I always stream effectively - however while traveling I would like to have it on my phone's 'harddrive'. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a smart playlist with the attribute `iCloud Status, is, Apple Music` and `Location, is not, on this computer`.
If you can change the `Apple music` attribute with `purchased`.
Also check the checkbox `live updating`.
[image]

Now you can make the playlist available offline by downloading it at your device.

More information: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19487?locale=en_US)